# Bootsrap input-form-addon height not aligning

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's input-form-addon is not aligning, as shown in the screenshot below. I've looked through many questions with no solution.

[image: Can't fix the height with CSS]

I've tried CSS to fix the height of .input-form-addon, but it doesn't change. Are there any errors in my code below? I'm using Contact form 7 plugin which generates its own classes.

```
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
     <span class="input-group-addon" style="height: 46px !important;">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 14px;">
        </i><br>
     </span><br>
     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
        <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control input-lg" id="contact-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email">
     </span>
 </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `<br>`'s http://www.bootply.com/RhW6e1DiQL

Comment: removing the `<br>` should solve the problem, any other case ?

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `<br>` from your markup.

**Working snippet**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
     <span class="input-group-addon" style="height: 46px !important;">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 14px;">
        </i>
     </span>
     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
        <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control input-lg" id="contact-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email">
     </span>
 </div>
```